How to use xaml page inside .net iOS project?
I have a project .NET7.0-ios, and I want to implement the Popups component inside my project(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup).
How can I implement this inside my project?
I want to create an xaml page and call. This component is from my native iOS environment.

Did you want to use the native iOS popup component?

You can create a popup page by refer to this document about Building a Popup.
If you want to use the native component directly, you can check this document about how to use the Native embedding - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn.
